# Primary decomposition of huge ideals using M2/Singular

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, matrices, computer-algebra

I used to ask similar questions in other communities, but so far never received any feedback.
Given four Hermitian $n\times n$ matrices $A_1,A_2,B_1,B_2$ together with the constraints $[A_i,B_j]=0$, I want to find the irreducible components of the algebraic set determined by $4(n^2-1)$ quadrics in the polynomial ring of $4n^2$ variables. I set up a decomposition into real and imaginary parts and finally got the resulting ideal using the following *Macaulay2* code:

```
reVars = (x,n) -> deepSplice for i from 1 to n list x_(i,i)..x_(i,n)  
imVars = (x,n) -> deepSplice for i from 1 to n list x_(i,i+1)..x_(i,n)  
generateRing = (Field,x,xx,y,yy,z,zz,w,ww,n) -> Field[reVars(x,n),reVars(xx,n),reVars(z,n),reVars(zz,n),imVars(y,n),imVars(yy,n),imVars(w,n),imVars(ww,n)]  
commutator = (A,B) -> A*B - B*A  
rePart = (R,x,n) -> genericSymmetricMatrix(R,x_(1,1),n)  
imPart = (R,y,n) -> genericSkewMatrix(R,y_(1,2),n)  
rePartCom = (R,x,y,z,w,n) -> commutator(rePart(R,x,n),rePart(R,z,n))-commutator(imPart(R,y,n),imPart(R,w,n))  
imPartCom = (R,x,y,z,w,n) -> commutator(rePart(R,x,n),imPart(R,w,n))+commutator(imPart(R,y,n),rePart(R,z,n))  
pairCom = (R,x,y,z,w,n) -> trim ideal unique flatten join(entries rePartCom(R,x,y,z,w,n), entries imPartCom(R,x,y,z,w,2))  
completeCom = (R,x,xx,y,yy,z,zz,w,ww,n) -> pairCom(R,x,y,z,w,n) + pairCom(R,x,y,zz,ww,n) + pairCom(R,xx,yy,z,w,n) + pairCom(R,xx,yy,zz,ww,n)  
totalCom = (R,x,xx,y,yy,z,zz,w,ww,n) -> completeCom(R,x,xx,y,yy,z,zz,w,ww,n) + pairCom(R,x,y,xx,yy,n) + pairCom(R,z,w,zz,ww,n)

kk = ZZ/101
R = generateRing(kk,x,xx,y,yy,z,zz,w,ww,n)
I = completeCom(R,x,xx,y,yy,z,zz,w,ww,n)
```

This works fine and gives me the ideal I depending on the dimension $n$.
If I now compute the primary decomposition

```
primaryDecomposition I
```

for $n=2$ the computation takes about 0.75 sec.
I got three radical (prime) components:
$I_1$ is generated by all quadrics such that also $[A_1,A_2]=[B_1,B_2]=0$ holds.
$I_2$: generators imply that $A_1,A_2$ are (real) diagonal matrices with vanishing trace.
$I_3$: generators imply that $B_1,B_2$ are (real) diagonal matrices with vanishing trace.

I'd like to see the behaviour for higher dimensions but just increasing the dimension to $n=3$ left me with the output

```
/bin/sh: line 1: 3045 Killed: 9
```

after approx 12 hours of processing.

What am I doing wrong? Is there any way to speed up the computation either from the mathematical or the M2 side? As you can see, I already reduced my field from QQ to a fraction field. Is Singular better for this particular task because I can choose between different algorithms for primary decomposition?
Any help or hint is highly appreciated!

Comment: I'd suggest you ask on the M2 google group.  However, can you give me some specifics on what version of M2 you are running, also, what computer/OS/RAM are you using?  Also, do you want the primary decomposition, or just the (minimal?) associated primes?  In some cases the latter can be a lot faster.  There are some other tricks too if you already know some of the primary components.

Comment: One other thing you can try is to use a different monomial order.

Comment: @KarlSchwede: Thanks for your feedback.
1. I used to ask this question in the M2 google group but did not receive an answer so far.
2. I recently updated to M2 version 1.18 and use a 2015 Macbook with BigSur 11.3.1 and 8GB RAM.
3. I edited my question, so you can see that in two dimensions all components were already minimal primes. So yes, I am only interested in those but an earlier computation of minimal primes gave me a "Too many heap sections"-error.
4. From my edits, I guess that those ideals generated by the conditions of $I_1,I_2,I_3$ may carry over to higher dimensions.

Comment: So too many heap sections is a ram issue.  I would suggest trying to run it on a different machine with more ram and so that M2 is compiled/configured in a way to use it.  There is some discussion on the too many heap sections error recently.  Years ago I solved it on a machine with 64gigs of ram by recompiling M2 from source (see the google group).   Sorry I'm not more help.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a real expert, but these problems can be absolute monsters for exact algorithms. I don't think you are doing anything wrong. Numerical irreducible decomposition might be a more feasible alternative; find yourself an expert in [Bertini](https://bertini.nd.edu) and try your problem with them.